# Reading input from standard input

Tags: c, string

I want to have a terminal running a process and while running I want to send commands to the process over the same terminal. The process runs in a while loop and takes several commands and some of these commands have optional parameters. For example, send a 'PRINT ID', where ID is optional. At the moment I have this

```
char *command = malloc(100);
while(1) {
 fgets(command , 100 , stdin);
 if( strcmp(command, "PRINT") == 0 ) {
 /*do something*/
```

but the `strcmp` always fails and I don't know how C can extract the optional parameter and use it in the function.

Comment: The terminal does not seem relevant to your question, which seems to be: How can I read strings from standard input. While your actual problem seems to be: "How can I compare strings?".

Comment: You can use `strncmp`. If library don't allow, you can write your own `strncmp`.

Comment: It's probably a good time to read about *parsing*.

Comment: try `strcmp(command, "PRINT\n")`

Comment: Do one thing...first just print the value of command. Also note that its better to cast malloc into char* as it points to void for the moment

Answer (score 1):

@BLUEPIXY is correct.

According to the documentation of [fgets](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets):

Reads at most `count - 1` characters from the given file stream and stores them in the character array pointed to by str. Parsing stops if end-of-file occurs or a newline character is found, **in which case str will contain that newline character**. If no errors occur, writes a null character at the position immediately after the last character written to str.

So, what you are looking for is `strcmp(command, "PRINT\n") == 0`.

You can avoid this by using `fscanf` instead:

```
fscanf(stdin, " %100[^\n]", command);
if(strcmp(command, "PRINT") == 0) {
    /* do something */
}
```